# QT, undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()'

Tags: c++, qt, undefined-reference, openalpr

I am trying to run OpenALPR on QT. I installed it [here](https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Compilation-instructions-(Ubuntu-Linux)). I can test it from terminal successfully. I got the error in the title on QT. Undefined reference error is caused by unlinked library but I add the `libopenalpr.so` under the path `/usr/lib` to the .pro file. Why I get that error?

My cpp file:

```
#include "alpr.h"
int main()
{
    alpr::Alpr openalpr("us", "etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf");
}
```

My pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
TARGET = OpenAlprTry
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -L -lopenalpr
```

Comment: You add the libopenalpr in the progile with -lopenalpr true. However, the -L option (which is used to indicate the path to the library) has no parameter. You should do something like -L /usr/lib -lopenalpr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pkg-config to link with your wanted library.
Add to .pro file:

```
unix: CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
unix: PKGCONFIG += openalpr
```

Package name could be different or you could need to add more packages.

To check pkg-config names type in your terminal:

```
pkg-config --list-all | grep openalpr
```

and add packages like that

```
unix: PKGCONFIG += package1 package2 package3
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you first check whether openalpr library is in the library path? IF not add the library path to the .pro file.

Comment: it is under the /usr/lib

Comment: try giving -L/usr/lib -lopenalpr

Comment: It worked. I know that usr/lib is the default directory that QT check libraries. Why didn't QT find the library?

Comment: You can find more information regarding it here, http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html